# Laravel - Mysql Where Not In join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, inner-join

I have three tables i.e. `users`, `galleries`, `orders`. the structure is simple. both `galleries` and `orders` have a column named `client_id` acting as a foreign key for `users`
I need a result set with the list of only those `users` that are present in `galleries` but not in `orders`.
I have tried following but it gives me all the users that are present in `orders`

```
$users  =   DB::table('galleries')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'galleries.client_id')
        ->join('orders', 'orders.client_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('galleries.client_id', 'galleries.path', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'orders.order_number')
        ->where('galleries.session_id', null)
        ->where('galleries.is_video', '1')
        ->where('galleries.is_thumb', '0')
        ->get();
    dd($users);
```

The query produced by upper code is

```
    select
  `galleries`.`client_id`,
  `galleries`.`path`,
  `users`.`first_name`,
  `users`.`last_name`,
  users.id,
  `orders`.`order_number`
from
  `galleries`
  inner join
  `users`
    on
      `users`.`id` = `galleries`.`client_id`
    inner join
    `orders`
      on
        `orders`.`client_id` = `users`.`id`
where
  `galleries`.`session_id` is null
  and
  `galleries`.`is_video` = '1'
  and
  `galleries`.`is_thumb` = '0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Not sure if it works:

```
DB::table('galleries')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'galleries.client_id')
    ->select('galleries.client_id', 'galleries.path',
             'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
    ->where('galleries.session_id', null)
    ->where('galleries.is_video', '1')
    ->where('galleries.is_thumb', '0')
    ->whereNotIn('client_id', function($query) {
        $query->select('client_id')
              ->from('orders');
    })
    ->get();
```

I've removed the `orders.order_number` because according to your requirement, you mentioned *select those galleries which the user doesn't have an order*. If there is no order for the client, how to join the orders?

I simply provided an additional `whereNotIn` which it reads as "where the client_id doesn't exist in the orders table".

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed

Comment: It took me a while to find these docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping